# Use of pointer to const

Tags: c, pointers

From the man page of qsort, in an example of sorting strings:

```
 static int
       cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
       {
           /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
              pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
              to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */

           return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
       }
```

Why is it necessary to have `char * const *` in the arguments to `strcmp()`? Isn't `char *` enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const void* p1` says that whatever `p1` points at is not changed by this function.  If you did

```
char** p1_copy = (char**) p1;
```

that would be a setup to potentially break that promise, because you could then do

```
*p1_copy = "Something else";
```

So a cast from `const void*` to `char**` is said to "cast away const".  Legal, but some compilers will warn if you use a cast to both cast away const and otherwise change the type at once.

The cast that doesn't break the promise of the `const void* p1` declaration is the one used:

```
char* const* p1_arg = (char* const*) p1;
```

Now `*p1_arg`, the thing `p1` points to, can't be changed just like we said.  You could change the characters in it though:

```
*p1_arg[0] = 'x';
```

The function declaration never said anything about them, and you say you know them to originally be non-`const char`s.  So it's allowable, even though the function doesn't actually do any such thing.

Then you dereference that (as an rvalue) to get a `char*`.  That can legally be passed as the `const char*` argument to `strcmp` by automatic `const` promotion.

Comment: It helps to think about the type name in reverse.  `const void*` is "pointer to `const void`", whereas `char* const*` is "pointer to `const` pointer to `char`".  Notice that the constness of the pointed-to type doesn't change, only the underlying type changes (`void` to `char*`).

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp` is declared as

```
int strcmp(
   const char *string1,
   const char *string2 
);
```

This properly expresses the function's interface contract - which is that `strcmp` will not modify its input data - and allows the compiler to optimize inside the function (assuming it were not part of the CRT, and likely in assembler already).

Comment: And a good compiler will flag a change to the pointer as an error too.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, if you wanted to get rid of the consts, the cast would be to `char **`, not `char *`. The `const` is left in the cast because the arguments to `cmpstringp` are also `const`.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison function passed to qsort has no business modifying the items it's comparing.

This is why the general case of qsort looks like:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Comment: There is no `const char *` in `char * const *`.

Comment: See recent edit. I was trying to make it to a meeting when I posted the original answer. I was simply trying to point out that it asks for `const char *` because it can't/shouldn't change the arguments.

Comment: Wow. Having a hard time being lucid today. Sorry. You're right.